# Dynamically Generate Html Graphic

Tags: css, html, dynamic

I am trying to figure out the best approach to dynamically generate this graphic. This can be 1 -> n circles with information connected to the baseline.

Please let me know how you have done this before or are familiar with an approach that may work.

Here is an image of the basic layout.

[image]

Here is an image of the client sample report.

[image]

Comment: How do you know which circles will be connected to which?

Comment: The circles are not going to be connected. Each individual circle will be connected to the center line. In the 2nd image the line has a connector circle that has no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic css for your shapes. You should be able to easily extend this pattern to rotate the shape for the ones on the bottom. Using css before and after helps keep your markup clean.

```css
.fizz { 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px; 
    background:#ddd; 
    border-radius:50%; 
    position:relative; 
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.fizz:before { 
    content:""; 
    height: 50px; 
    top: 49px; 
    left: 23px;
    position:absolute;
    border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
}
.fizz:after { 
    content:""; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    top: 97px; 
    left: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fizz"></div>
<div class="fizz"></div>
<div class="fizz"></div>
<div class="fizz"></div>
```